# What is the meaning of the following line of code?

Tags: ado.net, sqldatareader

I am learning ADO.NET and now I am trying to understand the SqlDataReader. I am trying to learning by using [this tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) and I am facing some difficulties now in understanding the following part of the code mentioned [HERE](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04):

```
while (rdr.Read())
    {
        // get the results of each column
        string contact = (string)rdr["ContactName"];
        string company = (string)rdr["CompanyName"];
        string city    = (string)rdr["City"];

        // print out the results
        Console.Write("{0,-25}", contact);
        Console.Write("{0,-20}", city);
        Console.Write("{0,-25}", company);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

I want to understand the meaning of "{0, -25}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the `WriteLine` method schould print the value of the first parameter, in your case contact, to a width of 25 characters. The minus in front of the 25 indicates a left justified output.

Answer (score 2):

That is a format specifier for .NET Console.Write().
See documentation explaining here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xdyw6yk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IN SqlDataReader, it reads record from database based on query.
sqlDataReader read record at a time single row. it means rdr["ContactName"] is one value and it read and move to  string contact and so on every fields.
It fetch all record in while loop.
And Console.Write("{0,-25}", contact) is used to format output.